# Removing the total navigation history windows store app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there any way that I can clear the navigation history of pages in windows store apps i.e. a windows store app that is built using HTML/CSS and Javascript?

I have tried searching the MSDN forums as well but wasn't able to find a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WinJS.Navigation.history = {};` should to the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The method from Tadeusz usually works fine, but mind that doing that will also set WinJS.Navigation.location to null.
I had a case with a custom combined navigation system where I did not call a WinJS.navigate after clearing the history and that would mess up the overall history.
I fixed that by only clearing "backStack" and "forwardStack", but leave "current" unharmed.

```
WinJS.Navigation.history.backStack = [];
WinJS.Navigation.history.forwardStack = [];
```